# The Server commited a Protocol Infraction

Tags: vb.net, git, http, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to access GitHub .diff's content and I've been created a Curl command. The following command is:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: token MyGitHubToken' -H      "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.diff" https://api.github.com/repos/[USR]/[REPO]/commits/[COMMITID]
```

The command is valid and I can obtain the .diff content. So I translated the command to VB code:

```
Dim url As New Uri("https://api.github.com/repos/[USR]/[REPO]/commits/[COMMITID]")
Dim myReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
myReq.Headers.Clear()
myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization: token MyGitHubToken")
myReq.Accept = "application/vnd.github.v3.diff"
myReq.Method = "GET"
myReq.KeepAlive = False
Try
      myReq.KeepAlive = False
      Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(myReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
      Dim reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
      Dim res As String = String.Empty
      reader.Close()
      response.Close()
Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

But in the line of `GetResponse()` it  throws the exception:

> The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine.

I set the property `KeepAlive` of `myReq` to `False`, but it still throws the same error.